# How to return first non-blank value with LOOKUP function

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016, database, lookup

I have a table:

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BQDN.png) in which I reference data from a dataset using a LOOKUP function. I can reference columns(such as new_deaths) which have the latest(non-blank) data just fine. However, for some columns such as Total Vaccinations, the latest data is not available so when I try to use the LOOKUP function, I get a 0 (blank) instead. I would like to skip the blank values and return the first numeric value.

Picture clarification: I reference another [sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpGOt.png) that's called World.

The column New Deaths returns the latest values since the last entry in the World sheet is not blank. For the Total vaccinations in millions it returns a 0. The raw data can be found on OurWorldInData.org

Comment: Please [edit] your post & share the formula you are trying so far will help us to fix the issue!! [Mean while U check this](https://superuser.com/questions/1646012/excel-formula-to-get-last-non-zero-or-not-blank-value-in-column-and-return-value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you try this formula `=IFERROR(LOOKUP(1,0/(($A2=World!C:C)*(World!AI:AI<>"")),World!AI:AI),"")`

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you Emily. This formula worked beautifully. If I may ask, how does this formula work? and is it possible to write a formula which takes the resulting total vaccination number to report the date as well?

Comment: @Moe This formula is to find the value that meet multiple conditions in order, like **Location** and non-blank **total_vaccinations** value.`($A2=World!C:C)*(World!AI:AI<>"")`. If you needed, you could also add a date condition.